# Using data from stateful service into controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I know its not the best practice to have stateful services in angularJS but sometimes it makes sense when you want one service method to return multiple values. For example in my casei would be required to execute a load method in service that would fire multiple asynchronous REST Calls to fetch all the initialization data, store it in multiple instance variables in the service and then any of the controllers can access it as and when required. This would sum up the entire initialization phase of the applications.Here is my service

```
    (function(){

    var dataService = function($http){

        this.landTransportTypes=[];
        var self = this;
        this.loadTransportTypes = function(mode){       
            return $http.get('/porteo-webapp/rest/init/transporttype/'+mode).success(function(response){
                this.landTransportTypes = response.data;
                console.log("In Service : "+self.landTransportTypes);               
            })
        };  

        return {    
            landTransportTypes:self.landTransportTypes,
            loadTransportTypes:this.loadTransportTypes
        };

    };

    angular.module('myApp').service('dataService',dataService);

}());
```

And here is how i wish to access service instance variable in my controller

```
dataService
    .loadTransportTypes('LAND')
    .then(function(){
        console.log(dataService.landTransportTypes)
    });
```

But i dont get anything in the controller. What is the way to obtain stateful data in controller ?

Comment: You have a typo. You aliased `this` as `self` but your callback refers to `this`. Also, `success` is deprecated, use `then` instead.

Comment: Do you mean my callback should be self.loadTransportTypes. I dont completely understand the change that i should make

Comment: Yes, because `this` inside of the success callback actually refers to the global object (window in a browser) because you forgot `"use strict;"`. Always add `"use strict;"` at the top of your file. If you do, you will get an error for this bug. Anyway, the whole point of `var self = this` is to refer to the service instance inside of the callback.

Comment: @AluanHaddad. Well nothing changed ! Still i am not getting anything in the controller. I have a feeling that immediately after firing the Async rest call, the control jumps back to the controller and performs the assignment to scope variable even before the response is received. Could it be a possibility. If that is the case then what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
(function(){

    var dataService = function($http){
        var self = this;
        this.loadTransportTypes = function(mode){       
            return $http.get('/porteo-webapp/rest/init/transporttype/'+mode).then(function(response){
                self.landTransportTypes = response.data;
                console.log("In Service : "+self.landTransportTypes);               
            })
        };
        this.landTransportTypes=loadTransportTypes('XXX');

        return {    
            landTransportTypes:self.landTransportTypes,
            loadTransportTypes:this.loadTransportTypes
        };

    };

    angular.module('myApp').service('dataService',dataService);

}());
```

Comment: Well nothing changed ! Still i am not getting anything in the controller.

Comment: This line `this.landTransportTypes=loadTransportTypes('XXX')` looks off. You are assigning a promise to a property that when executed, changes the value of that property, is that intentional?

Comment: @YeshodhanKulkarni I cant do that ! Even if it works i cant do `loadTransportTypes('xxx')`, The xxx parameter is dynamic and needs to be passed through the controller, I would prefer a cleaner approach

Comment: @AluanHaddad and so for `this.landTransportTypes=loadTransportTypes(mode)` to work i need to set the mode into the service. If you see mode is local variable to `this.loadTransportTypes(mode)`

Comment: no it is a parameter to `loadTransportTypes`. But this answer has other problems. It is using half `factory` half `service` style implementation. It is also assigning to a property incorrectly.

Comment: I understand that @YeshodhanKulkarni would want me to load as and when the service is instantiated. No i dont think so..that would overload my application. And startup would be slow..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144161/discussion-between-raghaveshukla-and-aluan-haddad).